# How to show that $f(p^{k}) = f(p) \cdot f(p^{k-1}) \Longrightarrow f(p^{k}) = [f(p)]^{k}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

If f is an arithmetic function such that $f (1) = 1$ and $p$ is a prime number. Prove that:

$\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$

$f(p^{k}) = f(p) \cdot f(p^{k-1}) \Longrightarrow f(p^{k}) = [f(p)]^{k}$

Comment: By arithmetic function do you mean linear functions ?

Comment: i guess i'm confused, because in the exercise page  i can't make the difference between integer part and parentheses, but i'll delete that condition and i´ll try again..
Thank you!!!

Comment: @Abstraction No, simply that it is defined on the naturals.

Comment: $f(p^4)=f(p)f(p^3)=f(p)(f(p)f(p^2)=f(p)(f(p)f(p)f(p)$. If you want to be formal, use induction.

Comment: $p$ being a prime is a red herring. It works for $p$ not prime too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested [in comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923350/how-to-show-this-result#comment1906114_923350), this can be easily shown using induction.

$1^\circ$ For $n=1$ the claim is true, since 
$$f(p^1)=f(p).$$

$2^\circ$ (inductive step)

Assume that the claim is true for $n-1$, we will prove that it is true for $n$.

$$f(p^n) \overset{(1)}= f(p)f(p^{n-1}) \overset{(2)}= f(p) [f(p)]^{n-1} = [f(p)]^{n}$$
In the equality (1) we have used the given condition. In the equality (2) we have used inductive hypothesis.